# How to import 3D models in Webots?

Tags: simulation, 3d-model, webots

I have 3D models with UV mapping and textures in Blender and I would like to import them in Webots. Can you please recommend the best way to do this?

Answer (score 1):

1. First you should export your Blender model to either obj(.obj) or Collada(.dae) format.
2. In Webots, you can then use the `CadShape` node. It is really simple and straightforward to use: just put the path to your .dae/.obj file in its url field. For more information see the documentation [here](https://cyberbotics.com/doc/reference/cadshape).

Your model should now be visible in Webots with its textures.

If you want more control over the different parts of the model, you can import each different mesh in a [Mesh node](https://cyberbotics.com/doc/reference/mesh) and then define a specific appearance for each mesh.

Comment: See also [this answer](https://robotics.stackexchange.com/a/24245/17975).