# How to import a 3D model in Webots_R2022b?

Tags: webots

I have a 3D model which is made by SolidWorks. I remember that in older versions there was a function to import 3D models but I can't find it in R2022b. Can you tell me how to import it? Thanks so much!

Comment: Did the answer help you? If so, please upvote and mark as the accepted answer. Thank you.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The functionality to import CAD models was removed from the latest versions of Webots because there is now a better way to handle this. Instead of importing a CAD model, you should now refer to it using a [CadShape](https://www.cyberbotics.com/doc/reference/cadshape) node. Simply insert a CadShape node in your scene tree at the desired location. It may be at root level or inside some other node. Set the `url` field to the point to your CAD file (prefer a relative path to an absolute path) and you are done:

```js
CadShape {
  url "model/my_model.dae"
}
```

The CadShape node supports the following 3D formats: DAE (Collada) and OBJ (Wavefront).

Alternatively, you may also consider using the [Mesh](https://www.cyberbotics.com/doc/reference/mesh) node which imports only the geometry of a CAD file, excluding the appearance and material information. In should inserted in the `geometry` field of a [Shape](https://www.cyberbotics.com/doc/reference/shape) node. In addition to DAE and OBJ formats, the Mesh node also supports the STL format.

*Disclaimer: I am a [Webots](https://github.com/cyberbotics/webots) developer working at [Cyberbotics](https://cyberbotics.com).*

Comment: Thanks for your help!