# How can I model a monorail robot in Webots by importing a Solidwork CAD model of robot?

Tags: mobile-robot, robotic-arm, simulation, webots, robotics-toolbox

I am new to Webots. I have not good idea about the considerations what should I consider when import a SolidWork CAD model to the Webots. I have a SolidWork model of robot. But I have not good idea to how should I place the coordinate systems and make relations between movements. Can anyone give some rough idea about the steps I should follow to correctly import a model to Webots?

Comment: This is an answer here, [How to import a 3D model in Webots_R2022b?](https://robotics.stackexchange.com/q/24227/9176). This question would be a duplicate of that question, except that, unfortunately, the answer has not been marked as the accepted answer.

Comment: What are the versions of SolidWorks and Webots? Please [edit] your question to include that information (do not place it in the comments).

Comment: the title question of your post does not match the rest of the post ... one is `how do I model?` ... the other is `how do I import?`

Answer (score 1):

Some tips when importing designs from Solidworks:

- Stick to the Webots recommendation for the objects's orientation FLU (x-Forward, y-Left, z-Up) for example the front facing the positive X-axis and the left side aligned with the positive Y-axis.
- Keep it simple; try to minimize the number of parts, especially with
  ball bearings, nuts, and bolts. Too many faces can slow down the
  simulation.
- Keep degrees of freedom straightforward. Stick to Standard mates; if
  it gets more complex, use a combination of simpler ones.
- Group moving parts together in subassemblies, and do the same for
  non-moving parts.
- Use a main Assembly to arrange subassemblies and establish a base frame incorporating non-moving components.
- In Solidworks, position the robot where you want it will be the origin position of the simulation in Webots . Use visualization modes to help with this.
- Pay attention to joints axis orientation for consistency. for example if a motor rotates in counterclockwise (positive) but is mounting upsidedowm the move result be clockwise (negative) you can flip this in Webots too.
- Create additional geometries for collision and import as separate mesh. You can do this manually using basic shapes.

take this tips make life easier, using the [Solidwork to URDF](https://wiki.ros.org/sw_urdf_exporter) plugin and then [URDFtoProto](https://github.com/cyberbotics/urdf2webots/tree/master) to seamlessly bring it into Webots. **Happy robot importing!** ️